# Background image loaded on page change

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, background-image

I have the same background image on my whole web application(multi page not single page).Is it possible that background image stays loaded on internal link changes without using ajax?(I don't want to see a blank page between loading pages )

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you loading pages with ajax or just simple html/php ? If it's just php/html, you will always see blank screen while changing page

Comment: html,data-ajax="false".

Comment: What cache control have you got set up for the image?

Comment: I guess the best way to accomplish this is to use a jQuery plugin like [Pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/). Otherwise, you have to focus on site performance. Decrease filesizes, remove unnecessary codeblocks and files, cache images etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess pure theoretically there will be always be a gap between changing your backround while the parser loads new content into the container. Just the velocity of the engine prevents you to notice this. However... I also guess you know how to change your body backround-image in css as well. All in all your question isn't particulary precise like my redundant answer is.

Here's a proposition I use for (one of) my site(s) in jQuery:

```
image.fadeOut(300, function(){
if($(window).width()==1920){
image.css("background", "url('../your_pic_here.jpg')");
image.fadeIn(2200);
}
```

Just think away the fade-stuff and probably it helps your application.